# Merge multiple CNNs

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to perform `Conv1D` on multiple inputs in my model. So I have 15 inputs of size 1x1500 each, where each one is an input to a series of layers. So I have 15 convolutional models which I want to merge before Fully Connected Layer. I have defined the convolutional model in a function, but I cannot understand how to call the function and then merge them.

```
def defineModel(nkernels, nstrides, dropout, input_shape):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv1D(nkernels, nstrides, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(Conv1D(nkernels*2, nstrides, activation='relu'))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(MaxPooling1D(nstrides))
    model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    return model


models = {}
for i in range(15):
    models[i] = defineModel(64,2,0.75,(64,1))
```

I have successfully concatenated 4 models as follows:

```
merged = Concatenate()([ model1.output, model2.output, model3.output, model4.output])

merged = Dense(512, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.75)(merged)
merged = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.75)(merged)
merged = Dense(40, activation='softmax')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=[model1.input, model2.input, model3.input, model4.input], outputs=merged)
```

How do I do it for 15 layers in the for loop as writing 15 layers separately isn't efficient?

Comment: Are the multi inputs you are using related to each other? Are they supposed to be fed to their respective models in parallel ? Also, are you planning to train the model separately or simultaneously ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best you can do is use the functional API everywhere:

```
def defineModel(nkernels, nstrides, dropout, input_shape):
    l_input = Input( shape=input_shape )
    model = Conv1D(nkernels, nstrides, activation='relu')(l_input)
    model = Conv1D(nkernels*2, nstrides, activation='relu')(model)
    model = BatchNormalization()(model)
    model = MaxPooling1D(nstrides)(model)
    model = Dropout(dropout)(model)
    return model, l_input


models = []
inputs = []
for i in range(15):
    model, input = defineModel(64,2,0.75,(64,1))
    models.append( model )
    inputs.append( input )
```

Then it is easy to recover the lists of inputs and the outputs of the submodels and merge them

```
merged = Concatenate()(models)

merged = Dense(512, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.75)(merged)
merged = Dense(1024, activation='relu')(merged)
merged = Dropout(0.75)(merged)
merged = Dense(40, activation='softmax')(merged)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=merged)
```

Normally, these operations are not a bottle neck. None of this should have a major impact during training or inference

Comment: Works really fine. Thank you!!

Comment: I have another error which goes like this `Error when checking target: expected dense_3 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (240, 40)` , I have written the code as you suggested and then my next line is as follows  `model.fit(xx[0:15], label, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=25, epochs=30)`.    Here label is of size 240x40 and input I have is of size 240x15x1500.

Comment: xx is of shape [240,15,1500]?

Comment: No my bad. xx is a list. I am actually getting some input as 240x15x1500 which i want to split as 1x1500 so that I can give the input to model. I have written a code like this `xx = np.split(data,15,axis=1)`

Answer (score 2):

Of course, as @GabrielM suggested, using functional API is the best way to do this, however if you don't want to modify the `define_model` function you can also do it like this:

```
models = []
inputs = []
outputs = []
for i in range(15):
    model = defineModel(64,2,0.75,(64,1))
    models.append(model)
    inputs.append(model.input)
    outputs.append(model.output)


merged = Concatenate()(outputs) # this should be output tensors and not models

# the rest is the same ...

model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=merged)
```